# Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) for Visual Studio | Can't load project

Tags: installation, visual-studio-cordova

I've installed the CTP Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for VS 2013.2

There's no project template for hybrid apps and when i open a example project i get this error:

```
D:\Downloads\WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps\JavaScript\WinJSToDo\WinJSToDo.jsproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Users\kevin.martins\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  D:\Downloads\WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps\JavaScript\WinJSToDo\WinJSToDo.jsproj
```

Comment: Could you verify from the File->New dialog in Visual Studio, if the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps project template shows up under JavaScript or TypeScript sections?

Comment: These templates are not present.
Mean while, I've removed vs 2013 and installed a fresh vs 2013.2 
and off course afterwards the CTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd situation and should generally not occur. It seems the VSIX file got copied over but was not installed correctly.

Here's the work around (run using an administrative command prompt):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /admin /uninstall:MultiDeviceHybridApps..db151788-9b27-49db-a5e2-d25a2653eb83
```

This removed the broken entries for the VSIX from the previous failed attempt to install. Following this, issue another command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" "%localappdata%\Microsoft\MultiDeviceHybridApps\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.vsix" /admin
```

At this point, the VSIX should be installed successfully and the templates will become available in Visual Studio.

Comment: To me, it partially works, (+1) I can see now the templates for apache but the ionic template didnt work (I came from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831683/unable-to-create-apache-cordova-project-in-visual-studio-2013)