# Visual Studio/Multi Device Hybrid Apps CTP / Cordova - The imported project was not found

Tags: node.js, target, visual-studio-cordova

When I attempt to create a new blank Cordova app in Visual Studio 2013 with the Multi Device Hybrid Apps CTP I get the following error message.

[image]

Has anybody else experienced this? I was thinking that it could be a Node/NPM issue but they both work correctly on my machine (before and after the install).

---

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that I already tried the answer found here: [Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) for Visual Studio | Can't load project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212443/multi-device-hybrid-apps-preview-for-visual-studio-cant-load-project).

Comment: Looks this was answered here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212443/multi-device-hybrid-apps-preview-for-visual-studio-cant-load-project

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already tried that.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I was thinking that it could be a Node/NPM issue but they both work correctly on my machine (before and after the install)."

Comment: Because the error involves a node modules folder, the thought had crossed my mind that my Node installation could be part of the problem. However Node works and always has worked on my computer so I doubt that a good installation could be the cause of this. The fact that the product is in CTP is much more likely.

Comment: I work on the MDHA feature for Visual Studio and will inform the team about this issue - as you say that Priyank's advice didn't work, I can only suggest uninstalling and re-installing MDHA. Did you install the 1.1 release that shipped shortly after the original CTP?

Comment: @Dai - I tried repairing the installation and that didn't help matters. I uninstalled the CTP yesterday (took a **very** long time) but haven't gotten around to reinstalling it quite yet. I can confirm that I am using the 1.1 release.

Comment: @LeviBotelho Any news on this?  I'm having the exact same error just trying to open the blank project.  I'm using VS 2013 update 3 and the CTP2.0 release and see the exact same error.  Not sure if it matters, but node was already installed before installing CTP2.0.  Node v0.10.26.  I've tried a complete reinstall of MDHA with no success, and yes it takes forever to uninstall.

Comment: Still no news @JasonEades. I ended up switching to Ubuntu and Atom to do my dev while I wait for this issue to eventually be resolved...

Comment: @Dai I've got the same problem with community edition. Now I've found that the [two main pre-requirements](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC741960.png) for MDA3.1 is not available in community edition of VS2013

Comment: Could you solve it? Please add an answer if you could. Thanks! :)

Comment: I solved it by developing PhoneGap on Ubuntu with Atom ;).

Answer (score 1):

MDHA projects require that Node be installed on your machine to be able to create a project. While you mention that NodeJS is installed, there's a possibility it may be stale or corrupted.

Try these steps:

- Close VS
- Uninstall NodeJS
- Reboot machine
- Install NodeJS from nodejs.org
- Start VS and try to create a project

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. For the record, I also attempted reinstalling the MDHA CTP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error as Levi and it was because a few directories were not created in the node_modules directory during installation.  Re-installing node and/or the entire CTP2.0, restarting, clapping my hands, screaming, etc would not fix this in my environment.  On another PC, this worked fine.  To fix this problem:

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\` and search for "vs-mda".  You should find both a "vs-mda" and "vs-mda-targets" folder. *(Make a recursively search, you won't find the folders exactly in "Extensions", there are inside of a random-named folder)*
2. Copy those two folders to the location the error is complaining
   about`%appdata%\npm\node_modules\`
3. Restart Visual Studio and the error should go away

Now, once this worked, I still got an error about the Git CLI missing.  That was solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202530/multi-device-hybrid-apps-installation-error).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'll have to try this. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @LeviBotelho, I will try http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249493/148271 before trying this one.