# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps installation error

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I installed the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps and

when i open the javascript cordova project , vs2013 show this message.

Git CLI The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

[image]

My Path variable

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a known issue with the CTP2 release. To fix this, in Visual Studio, go to:

- Tools->Options
- Scroll down to Multi-Device Hybrid Apps on the left
- Choose "Environment Variables" from the list
- Check mark the GIT_HOME variable
- Set it to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After installing [VS 2013 Update 5](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) followed by installation of the Apache Cordova  tools I had the same issue. Priyank's answer took me in the right direction though in my case the path to the variables is

- Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Environment Variable Overrides

Thank you Priyank!

Hope it is helpful.